# What events occurred between 17 Tamuz and 9 Av warranting a 3 week mourning period?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, three-weeks

What tragic historic events occurred during the 3 weeks between 17 Tamuz and 9 Av that warrants a mourning period? Also, why is there a more "severe" mourning period (i.e. - greater restrictions such as not eating meat) during the 9 days beginning from Rosh Hodesh Av until 9 Av?

Comment: Why do you mourn Shiva for seven days after the death of a relative instead of just on the day they die?

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting comparison. But, there is a specific precedent for 7 days which IIRC comes from the behavior of Ya'akov's children.

Comment: @DoubleAA Does one keep Shiva after the third Yahrtzeit also?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Tisha Bav isn't a Yahrtzeit. It's Aninut.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I don't understand your question. Please explain what you mean by 3rd yahrtzeit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Three Weeks are those days between 17 Tamuz, when the walls around Yerushalaim were breached by Titus's army, and 9 Av, when the Bais Hamikdash was actually destroyed.  It would have been a period of heavy fighting, more than just a siege.

As to your second question: The Gemara (Tanis) doesn't mention a mourning period starting from 17 Tamuz.  It's an Ashkenazi minhag, and I believe is not held among the Sefardim.  The Mishna in Tanis states `Mishenichnas Av m'ma'atin b'simcha`, which is the source of the 9 Days.  In addition, there are additional restrictions (in the Gemara) for `Shavua shechal bo`, the week in which 9 Av falls.

I understand that the fighting may have intensified in the later period.  There is mention of the Roman army entering Jerusalem on 7 Av, which begins a period of increased mourning (no siyum, etc.).

Comment: Menachem, Nevuchadnetzar breached on 17 Tammuz (Melachim ב, forget perek). I don't know about Titus, but in any case, please insert sources.

Comment: @Noach thats not true he breached on 9 Tammuz

Comment: @DoubleAA, I must misremember, I haven't gone through Melachim in some time

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I like your new English word, "misremember". I "mis"remember to use this term next time I forget something ;-)

Comment: @DanF, I believe that that is actually in the lexicon already (Source: built in Apple dictionary)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I'm sorry, I don't have the exact sources offhand.  The 2nd Bais Hamikdash was definitely on 17 Tamuz (Mishna Tannis 4:6, and Tos. YT, though it may be 3rd perek in Gemara).  The 1st Bais was, according to Melachim, 9 Tamuz.  There are those (I don't recall source) that say it was 17 Tamuz with Nevuchadnetzar as well, but the dates were confused because of starvation, and the error was left in place to make that point.